# How to verify a transaction that was made using Paystack link through an app in java

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, reactjs, node.js

I linked a paystack account using hyperlink in a javafx form. It took me to the paystack site where I paid for the services rendered. My problem is how to verify the paystack payment through another javafx login form such that when the user logs in, it confirms that the payment has been made, the amount, email and phone no. then signs the user in to another javafx form. In case you need to take a look at the paystack

I expected it to run this program after the login button is clicked and then be able to transfer me from the login page to the next javafx form after confirming that the payment was made in paystack. Note: Paystack is a payment gateway. In case you need access to the paystack, it is https://dashboard.paystack.com/#/login?next=app.settings.developers

```
public PaystackVerifyTransactionResponse verifyTransaction(String reference) throws Exception {
    PaystackVerifyTransactionResponse paystackresponse = null;
        try {
            HttpClient client = HttpClientBuilder.create().build();
            HttpGet request = new HttpGet("https://api.paystack.co/transaction/verify/"+ reference)
            request.addHeader("Content-type", "application/json");
            request.addHeader("Authorization", "Bearer" + "sk_test_xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx");//
            request.addHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache");
            //StringBuffer result = new StringBuffer();//used below stringbuilder
            StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
            org.apache.http.HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);//used this HttpResponse response = (HttpResponse) client.execute(request);
            //HttpResponse response = (HttpResponse) client.execute(request);
            //HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
            try{
            if (response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode() == OK) {
                BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent()));

                String line = null;
                while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
                    result.append(line);
                }
            }
            
            
           // else {
             //  throw new RuntimeException();// throw new Exception("Error Occured while connecting to paystack url");
               //     }
            }catch(Exception especial)
                {
                    throw new RuntimeException(especial);
                }
            
            //ObjectMapper mapper = null;
            
            ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
                    
               paystackresponse = mapper.readValue(result.toString(), PaystackVerifyTransactionResponse.class);//result.append(reference).toString()

           
            if (paystackresponse == null) {
                
                throw new Exception("An error occurred while verifying payment");
            } 
            else if (paystackresponse.verifyTransaction(reference).equals("false")) {
                throw new Exception("You may not seem to have paid");
            }
            else if (paystackresponse.verifyTransaction(reference).equals("success")) {
               //PAYMENT IS SUCCESSFUL, APPLY VALUE TO THE TRANSACTION
               mainapp.changeScene("classVideo.fxml");
               
               
            }
}
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }

        return paystackresponse;
    }

}
```